# Set Ecosia as default Search (Engine) Provider in Chrome / Firefox

Tags: windows-10, firefox, group-policy, browser-addons, search-engines

Our organisation is in the process of setting Ecosia as the default Search provider for all browsers and we will like achieve this by using the GPO template via your link here https://ecosia.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214140705-The-Ecosia-Group-Policy-Template-for-Chrome . When I downloaded and extracted the template i got an error saying

**"Namespace ‘Google.Policies.Chrome’ is already defined as the target namespace for another file in the store."**

I even went into the **chrome.admx** template file to modify this line in order to avoid conflicts

```
    <policyNamespaces>
    <target namespace="Google.Policies.Chrome" prefix="chrome"/>
    <using namespace="Google.Policies" prefix="Google"/>
    <using namespace="Microsoft.Policies.Windows" prefix="windows"/>
  </policyNamespaces>
```

since i realised in the **ChromSearchProdviderEcosia.admx** template file also has this namespace defined I renamed the namespace to something else and then tried again after several errors but didn't do the trick.

```
<policyNamespaces>
    <target namespace="Google.Policies.Chrome" prefix="chrome"/>
    <using namespace="Microsoft.Policies.Windows" prefix="windows"/>
  </policyNamespaces>
```

I am suspecting a conflicting namespace since I had already downloaded some google chrome policy templates into the same location -> ADMX/ADM store. 
Is there a way we can override this part of the template to avoid this conflict? Or a possibility of redefining the name space so it doesn’t trigger a conflict after realising that of google already exists?

I wasn’t able to add the Ecosia template to store due to this error. 
I have already contacted Ecosia Support but some general suggestions will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing the target namespace **"Google.Policies.Chrome"** with **"Ecosia.Policies.Ecosia.Chrome"** . Refer to snippet of schema where change was effected below ..

```
 <policyDefinitions revision="1.0" schemaVersion="1.0">
    <policyNamespaces>
    <target namespace="Ecosia.Policies.Ecosia.Chrome" prefix="chrome"/>
    <using namespace="Microsoft.Policies.Windows" prefix="windows"/>
    </policyNamespaces>
```